# How to print all missing occurrences of an attribute in XSLT 2.0 before terminating the processing?

Tags: xslt-2.0, dita-ot

I'm working on a DITA-OT plugin, and I have an XSLT template where I need to terminate the processing if any topic element does not contain an @appname attribute. While this approach works well, it stops the processing as soon as it encounters the first occurrence of a missing @appname attribute, which doesn't allow me to see any other missing occurrences in the log file.

My question is: is it possible to modify below XSLT template in a way that it first prints out all the missing occurrences of @appname and then terminates the XSLT processing?

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ')][not(@toc = 'no')][not(@processing-role = 'resource-only')]">
        <xsl:variable name="WORKDIR" select="'/work/'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="FileWithPath">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$WORKDIR"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@href, '#')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="TargetFile" select="document($FileWithPath, /)"/>        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@class, ' mapgroup/topicgroup ')">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>            
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="*[contains(@class, ' map/topicref mapgroup-d/topichead ')] or contains(@class, ' map/topicref mapgroup-d/topichead ')">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <topic>                            
                            <xsl:if test="not($TargetFile/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/prolog ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/resourceid ')][@appname = 'abc'])">
                                <xsl:message terminate="yes">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="'Error: Topic does not contains appname '"/><xsl:value-of select="$TargetFile/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/@id"/>                                    
                                </xsl:message>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </topic>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: It seems your code (as it uses the `document` function) processes at least two input documents. Where are you looking for the missing (or wrong?) `appname` attributes? Is that the single file you are accessing with `$TargetFile`? Or are you loading different target files? You can of course use checks like `<xsl:if test="position() = last()"`> to test you process the "last" element, but how/whether that works depends on the input structure and the rest of the XML. Basically we need to see more context.

Comment: I have now updated those variables. the 'work' folder contains multiple xml files.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, declare a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="element-count" select="count(//*[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ')][not(@toc = 'no')][not(@processing-role = 'resource-only')])"/>
```

otherwise declare that variable locally in your template.

Then add e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:number level="any" count="*[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ')][not(@toc = 'no')][not(@processing-role = 'resource-only')]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then replace your

```
                         <xsl:if test="not($TargetFile/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/prolog ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/resourceid ')][@appname = 'abc'])">
                            <xsl:message terminate="yes">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'Error: Topic does not contains appname '"/><xsl:value-of select="$TargetFile/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/@id"/>                                    
                            </xsl:message>
                        </xsl:if>
```

With e.g.

```
                         <xsl:if test="not($TargetFile/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/prolog ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/resourceid ')][@appname = 'abc'])">
                            <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="$pos = $element-count">
                                <xsl:message terminate="yes">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="'Error: Topic does not contains appname '"/><xsl:value-of select="$TargetFile/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/@id"/>                                    
                                </xsl:message>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:message terminate="no">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="'Error: Topic does not contains appname '"/><xsl:value-of select="$TargetFile/*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]/@id"/>                                    
                                </xsl:message>
                              </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:if>
```